# Get Filename with Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Using Cordova, how can i get the filename with extension based on the URI of the file?

Example, in my application, these two URIs are used:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp.mobile.subdomain/cache/IMG_20180503_125311.jpg?1529347191687

content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A690
```

The first is easy to get the name, but the second is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI('file://example.jpg', function (fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function (myFile) {

        return myFile.name;

    }, function () {
        console.log('error');
    });

}, function (e) { });
```